# POST Request Returns Empty First TIme, Then Isn't empty every time after

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, global-variables

For Some Reason, The POST request for a link below returns empty the first time and then isn't empty every time after. If I change the email and make a new request, it returns the last user called for. It seems that the array is retaining its value on the server. I used the array because a global variable wasn't being defined by the promise chain from the fetch call. Below is the code for the server, as well as the request from Postman. I think this can be solved by figuring out how to define the global var in the fetch call, but every solution I've researched has failed.
**Server Side Code:**

```
//add in external libraries and requirements
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config({ path: './.env' })
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
var cors = require('cors')
const fs = require('fs')
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
let resultarr = []
let resultarr1 = []
//encryption
const key = process.env.KEY
function fakeMathRandom(callBack) {
  if(!callBack) throw new Error("Must provide callBack function");
  let seed=0;
  const randomOutputs = [0.04,0.08,0.15,0.16,0.23,0.42,0.52,0.65,0.79,0.89];
  const Math_random = Math.random;
  Math.random = function() {return randomOutputs[seed++ % 10];}
  const callbackOutput = callBack();
  Math.random = Math_random;
  return callbackOutput;
}

// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
 
// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

//serve static files
var publicdir = __dirname + '/public';
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 console.log(req)
    if (req.path.indexOf('.') === -1) {
    var file = publicdir + req.path + '.html';
    fs.exists(file, function(exists) {
      if (exists)
        req.url += '.html';
      next();
    });
  }
  else
    next();
});
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static(publicdir));

// POST request
app.post('/email', jsonParser, function (req, response) {
  var email = (req.body.email)
  var password = (req.body.password)
  var result;
  var url = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyC-BUGGSsvUX8z4W1LcsJzS59yrL4__EsE";
var payload = {
  email: email,
  password: password,
  returnSecureToken: true

};

 var options = {
     method: 'post',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     body: JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
//make fetch call
load =(url, options) =>{
  return fetch(url, options).then(response => response.json());
}
load(url,options).then(result => {
    // result is the parsed JSON - i.e. a plan ol' javascript object
   resultarr[0] = result
});
response.send(resultarr[0])
})
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send(resultarr[0]);
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`app listening at port:${port}`)
  });
```

**Postman API Request (Curl)**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://splurket.us/email' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
  "password": "Testing123",
  "returnSecureToken": true

}'
```

**Emails You Can use For Testing The Endpoint:**

1. **Email:** Testinguser@gmail.com | **Password:** Testing123
2. **Email:** Testinguser1@gmail.com | **Password:** Testing123

Comment: `resultarr[0] = result` inside `load(url, options).then(result =>` is retrieved AFTER you `response.send(resultarr[0])` - since, promises are asynchronous - put the `response.send(resultarr[0])` inside the `.then` ...

Comment: Is there any other way to use the result outside of a promise function?

Comment: only in another `.then`, or you can use `async`/`await` syntax - but what's wrong with my suggestion, it's perfectly valid

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. So In Express, you can just use the async function shown below and then you can use await since it is inside an async function.

```
app.post('/email', jsonParser, async function (req, response) {
var email = req.body.email
var password = req.body.password  
var result;
  var url = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyC-BUGGSsvUX8z4W1LcsJzS59yrL4__EsE";
var payload = {
  email: email,
  password: password,
  returnSecureToken: true

};

 var options = {
     method: 'post',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     body: JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  const res = await fetch(url, options);
  const result = await res.json();
  response.send(result)

})
```